# Configuring Apache content negotiation for languages using MultiViews

Tags: apache-2.2, content-negotiation

I'm attempting to get the `MultiViews` option working in Apache to vary the content returned to the browser based on the `Accept-Language` provided in requests.

I've got the following configuration:

```
Alias /multiviewstest "C:/MultiViews Test"

<Directory "C:/MultiViews Test">
    Options MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

In my `C:\MultiViews Test` directory I have the following files:

- `spam.html`
- `foo.html.en`

When I request `http://localhost/multiviewstest/spam` the contents of `spam.html` is returned. Here are the request and response headers:

```
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.10) Gecko/2009042316 Firefox/3.0.10 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 300
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

Date: Fri, 08 May 2009 11:07:54 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.10 (Win32)
Content-Location: spam.html
Vary: negotiate
TCN: choice
Last-Modified: Fri, 08 May 2009 10:48:34 GMT
Etag: "0-4-469645ec81e70;469645ff5a5d8"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 4
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

The `Content-Location`, `Vary`, and `TCN` response headers indicates `MultiViews` have correctly kicked in.

I've configured English as the only preferred language for displaying languages in my browser; an `Accept-Language en` header is set on requests. When I request `http://localhost/multiviewstest/foo.html` a 404 response is returned. Based on my understanding of [Apache's file naming conventions for language negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#naming) I'd expect the contents of the `foo.html.en` file to be returned.

Here are the request and response headers:

```
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.10) Gecko/2009042316 Firefox/3.0.10 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 300
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

Date: Fri, 08 May 2009 11:08:39 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.10 (Win32)
Content-Length: 221
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Here's what appears in the access log for the request:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [04/May/2009:10:28:24 +1200] "GET /multiviewstest/foo.html HTTP/1.1" 404 221
```

And from the error log:

```
[Mon May 04 10:28:24 2009] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: C:/MultiViews Test/foo.html (None could be negotiated).
```

**Why isn't the content negotiation for the language correctly kicking in? Is there some configuration I have overlooked?**

Comment: Have you looked at both your error and access logs?

Comment: I've added the appropriate entries from the logs to the post.

Comment: Can you post both the request and response headers of the successful (spam) and unsuccessful (foo) requests?

Comment: Done; I've added the headers for both the requests into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the proper language/extension relationships exist in your configuration?

```
AddLanguage en .en
LanguagePriority en fr de
ForceLanguagePriority Fallback
```

Comment: Bingo! An AddLanguage directive was enough to fix the problem, but I'll check out the other directives too. It would have been helpful if the Apache content negotation documentation I linked mentioned something about the AddLanguage directive. Nonetheless, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I ran into a similar issue, with the proper AddLanguage etc directives in place.  Eventually I realized that the problem was PHP-specific.

For some reason I was using SetHandler within a FilesMatch directive:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Switching to a simple AddType solved the problem:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Answer (score 0):

The [answer given by metkat](https://serverfault.com/a/176717/145213) hinted at the source of my trouble as well. However, I decided for a different approach. This is what my config had:

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

And this is what I changed it into:

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)(\.[a-z]{2}|)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

I basically added to the end of the file name: `(\.[a-z]{2}|)`, which means "...followed by a dot and two characters of the range a-z OR (`|`) nothing". Seems to work smoothly so far :)